# Why doesn't Supergirl make a time-paradox to save Krypton?

Tags: dc, time-travel, arrowverse, supergirl, flashpoint-paradox

This is a follow-on to this:
[Why doesn't Superman make his own Flashpoint paradox to save Krypton?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153087/why-doesnt-superman-make-his-own-flashpoint-paradox-to-save-krypton/)

That question asks why doesn't superman go back in time and do something to save Krypton or at least some Kryptonians from the doom.

**Question:**
Why doesn't Supergirl make her own Flashpoint paradox to save Krypton?

**Elaborations:**
The motivations for Superman to not make a paradox, as enumerated in the answer to the previous question, include:

1. Krypton's Red sun doesn't give the powers that a yellow sun does, so the super part goes away.
2. Kryptonian Skepticism (aka super-resistant to being saved) makes them actively resist rescue attempts
3. Time travel (nearly) always explodes badly/horribly/devastatingly
4. A super-rigid morality on the part of the Kryptonian, such as Superman has, would disallow such actions.

While these are particularly true for Superman/Kal-El, there are some differences for Supergirl/Kara.  Not only is she going to have stronger motivation to save Krypton, she is more likely to engage them in the face of their risk and complexity, and more likely to act if she thinks it is plausible.

Differences

- She is a lot more about the team than about a single individual.  This means she is surrounded by people who are super-hero/best-on-the-planet in their own way that she leans on, and is challenged by.  Her ability to think "outside the box" and rely on resources outside her own strengths is going to be substantially larger than her cousins.  She is going to find alternatives to "blocked paths" that her cousin wouldn't. (Reason 1)
- She grew up there.  Her biological parents died there.  Every friend she had up to the day she was sent to earth, lived there and died there.  She has roots there.  She has people she loved and would very much like to save.  Knowing it might be possible would be a compelling motive. She is also a product of that stubborn skepticism, and is likely to be more unrelenting even in the face of utter obliteration like they were. (Reason 2)
- She didn't grow up on earth in the same way he did.  He has decades of fighting bad guys and seeing how bad the best laid plans go astray.  She doesn't have a truckload of experience yelling "don't do it". (reason 3)
- Risk-taking and bold action are more part of her character than they are for Kal-El's character.She has the impulsiveness and brave lack-of-wisdom endemic to youth to make her more likely to act. (reason 4)
- Her exposure to the Flash is across genders, and in the show they seemed to have an attraction/tension that might lead her to make assumptions and take actions about parallel-universe travel and time-travel that are more risk taking and bold.  Kara doesn't know what a time-wraith is.  (Motivation)
- Her mind is more capable of nuance and complexity than his.  He is very often "when you are a hammer every problem looks like a nail" while she is not.  This means she is capable of considering, supporting, and executing more complex solutions to more nuanced and complex problems than he is.  Consider her boss/mentor Cat Grant as a source of capability for this as well as Martian Manhunter (J'Onn) and her foster sister.  (reason 1,3,4)

**Disclaimer**: I watch much more TV than read comics, so the Kara I know is from the TV show.  (Arrowverse?)  The superman I know comes from lots of cartoons, and a few TV shows since.  If you have something to suggest from outside my limited experience, then I welcome it just as well as things from within my framework of understanding.

Comment: I think you are missing the single most important reason why Supergirl would be willing to risk everything to save Krypton while Superman isn't. SHE LIVED THERE! For Superman Krypton is just an idea, his parents just holograms in a crystal. But for Supergirl (assuming the origin where she left as a young teen) it was a real place with people she KNEW.

Comment: Flashpoint was created by.. and I know this is suprising... *the Flash*, who has the ability to travel through time. Supergirl does not. Beyond that, when Barry did it, it was a disaster, and he wouldn't likely be willing to purposefully do that again.

Comment: Your question seems specifically targetted at just the Arrowverse shows on the CW, but you also tagged it for the _Flashpoint: Paradox_ movie and the DC comics world as a whole. Can you clarify which continuity(ies) you're asking about?

Comment: I still don't understand why the downvotes, and if I knew what someone was looking for here I would fix it.  I would normally delete any question that I had asked with this kind of negative rating.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I felt sort of tempted to. You say, "Here's a bunch of reasons why character A doesn't do this, but what about character B?" While their situations and motivations are different, they're not drastically different. All of the logical reasons why Superman would avoid it still apply.

Comment: @phantom42 - so .. if I had asked without some of the statements addressing how this question is substantially different than the other one, it might have done less poorly?  Seeing how there was a comic book series along this line - I didn't know about the comic - it makes me feel like this was a valid question.

Comment: I and at least a few other users don't see them as being substantially different. That's likely why some users chose to downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### She's tried, more or less.

In the 2012/2013 Superman story arc [H'El on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%27El_on_Earth), Supergirl is wooed by a Kryptonian named H'El and is convinced to attempt to go back in time to stop the destruction of Krypton. Unfortunately, H'El's method of time travel involves creating an explosion large enough to wipe out the entire solar system.

**Supergirl plays an integral role in advancing H'El's goals but comes to her senses at the end of the story and stabs H'El with a Kryptonite shard, killing him.**

Or so they think.

Things get a little nutty after that. The H'El on Earth story arc ends here and the [Krypton Returns](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Krypton_Returns) arc begins. Basically, Superman, Superboy, and Supergirl travel in time to pre-explody Krypton to stop H'El from preventing Krypton's destruction (and enslaving its population in the process).

The important thing to remember here is that **the story illustrates the importance of maintaining the time stream and keeping history from getting all mucked up.** A major portion of the story revolves around H'El's time altering causing the end of the universe.

I'll post the [DC Comics Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Krypton_Returns) synopsis here if you're interested:

> Superman has been pulled into outer space by an unknown force. There, he meets up with Superboy and Supergirl. The three meet the Oracle, who explains them that H'El, who survived their earlier encounter, has managed to bring Krypton back to life. However, H'El also altered the timeline and they must stop him from destroying the universe. With the help of Faora, the Oracle's servant, the three heroes travel to different points of Krypton's history to stop H'El's plans. Superman travels to Kryptonopolis a few months before Krypton's destruction, where he meets his mother Lara.
>
> At first, Lara confuses Superman for an intruder and attacks him but stops after seeing the symbol of El in his armor. She also detects yellow sun radiation in his body and says he should wait for Jor-El. Superman watches Lara tell Jor-El that she is pregnant, but then his armor changes back to its usual colors. In that moment, Superman confronts a mysterious person who is aware about his travel in time.
>
> This stranger is in fact Jor-El, who came from one of the alternate futures created by H'El. Realizing he was the one who created H'El, Jor-El has come to the past to stop H'El from conquering Krypton. Superman and Jor-El travel to Krypton's core and fight H'El. At first, Jor-El wants to kill H'El but Superman instead uses H'El's own chronal powers against him and freezes him with his super-breath, locking H'El in a state of eternal limbo. As Superman and Supergirl are reunited in the present, the Oracle informs them that Superboy sacrificed his life to stop H'El. Mourning the loss of their friend, Superman and Supergirl return to Earth.

[image: H'El on Earth] [image: Krypton Returns]

Answer (score 6):

The answer to every question of this nature is "because the few people capable of doing it know that it's a terrible idea."

Your question seems to make the assumption that we're only talking about the CW television shows that make up the "Arrowverse" (e.g. you mention her sister, her relationship with The Flash, etc.) If we restrict ourselves to that universe, then here's what Kara knows about Flashpoint:

- The Flash is able to run so fast that he goes back in time, and can create paradoxes. *As far as we know*, neither Superman nor Supergirl can do this. (The Flash *is* faster than Superman in every continuity I know of, because Speed Force)
- The last time Barry did such a thing, he *ruined* the lives of any number of people he knows, including (in some ways) his own.
- There's an entire group of people -- the Legends -- who's entire purpose is to find and *fix* these time aberrations to prevent exactly the problems Barry caused.

If Kara were to somehow figure out how to time travel, and went back to save an entire *planet* from blowing up, there is no telling what kind of disaster she might create for herself. Remember, when Barry did it, he changed things that had *absolutely no connection* to himself (e.g. Diggle's kid's gender), because that's how time travel works. The disruption in the timeline ripples out away from the paradox, changing things (almost always for the worse) as a reaction to time being disturbed. A change on the level you're talking about could well cause something *worse* to happen than the destruction of just one planet with only 2 survivors.

Kara has no way of knowing. And she's a good person at heart. She's not going to risk the potential deaths of countless beings across the universe for what, in her mind, would be "selfish" reasons of getting her parents back. She has made peace with the tragedy, and in her mind, that would have to be good enough.

Answer (score -2):

The Guardian of the galaxy can go back one minute after Superman was sent to Earth, and save Krypton with the help of Supergirl.

Comment: Guardian of the Galaxy? Is this some character I haven't seen yet (watching Supergirl season 2 now), or do you mean the characters from the Marvel movies? Or, perhaps, the Guardians of the Universe, as in Green Lantern's bosses (not sure if they've shown up in the Arrowverse)?